# Conversion to maven made json related object unresolved

Tags: java, json, maven, pom.xml

I was working on a java web project, what I decided to give maven a try.
So I converted the project to maven (by going to Configure->Convert to Maven).
Then I got `JSONArray` cannot be resolved to a type` on all my json object that worked before.

I added the following to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20141113</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

But still no change - all json related object "cannot  be resolved".

Here is the full POM.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.Letsgo.rest</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.Letsgo.rest</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20141113</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

What else can I do?

Comment: What happens when you right click project-> Maven -> Update project

Comment: Try [gradle](http://gradle.org)?

Comment: Hi,
update project did not change anything :(

Comment: Is the problem only on your IDE or do the errors pop up when you do a Maven compile?

Comment: Why have you changed this `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` why not using the defaults. Source folder `src/main/java` and test in `src/test/java`etc. See [default layout](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).